# .bat file: functional malware or a joke?

Tags: batch-file, malware

On a forum I'm moderating, a user posted a .bat file containing the following code:

```
@echo off
:virus
del /f /q "c:\WINDOWS\system32" 
taskkill explorer.exe
tskill explorer
set /a _virus+=1
net user %_virus+% /add
goto virus
```

Is this a functioning malware that will do what it looks like at first glance, or just a joke to make it look like it will but doesn't have the right syntax?

Comment: Any script which attempts to delete system files/directories and continuously create users is no joke! [The script is available on YouTube](https://youtu.be/mSjkfkFHNvM) but is luckily absolutely rubbish, because it is very badly written. If you want to discover what it does or was intended to do, enter the commands at the Command Prompt, i.e. `del /?`, `taskkill /?`, `tskill /?`, `set /?`, `net user /?`, `goto /?` etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is pointless and futile.

Comment: @Comp I don't think, it's "very badly written". The author obviously knew, what he did and how to avoid any permanent harm to the system. No new users are created due to the variable trick (explained in my answer) Although I'm not sure, what happens when running it as administrator by accident with the `del` command (and I won't try). But I agree - the definition as "joke" is (at least) to be discussed. It's too easy to "correct" the syntax.

Comment: @Stephan, I don't believe it was someone clever trying to dupe people. If you watch the video, I linked, as I did, it seems to me as if that was their level of misunderstanding. _I didn't say that new users were created, or anything would be deleted, just that an attempt, i.e. the intent, was there to do so. You don't turn it into an Internet Explorer shortcut with icon if it's just meant to look clever._

Comment: For the fact of attempting to delete system32; simply `del c:\WINDOWS\system32`  won't work as the user by default does not have ownership nor perms to do such actions. For education, you will need to stop a few services and use the `takeown` & `icacls` for the perms. Nerveless, please always take caution when it comes to a script attempting to delete system32.

Comment: The `taskkill` command isn't even correctly formatted. Amateurs can be funny.

Comment: `/s` was missing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `C:\WINDOWS` folder should be safe (thanks to Microsoft) (write-protected).

`taskkill` has a wrong syntax and just gives a message saying so.

`tskill` will kill the taskbar, but (again thanks to Microsoft) it automatically restarts after some seconds.

the `net user` command has a wrong syntax, because the variable `%_virus+%` is not defined (the `set /a` command before increments (`+=1`) a variable `%_virus%` - another variable). This might be a programming failure, but I guess, it's by intention.

Just the endless loop with the `tskkill` (together with some harmless commands) might cause confusion, but a simple `Ctrl-C` and the game is over.

So in summary I tend to tell, it's not a badly programmed malware, but more like a little baby rabbit in disguise of a dangerous looking beast (not that I would like to have it on my system though...).